# question about cyclic groups and quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

Is a quotient group always cyclic.

I see nothing on the internet that tells me it's the case, but since a quotient group: $\Phi : G \rightarrow G/H$ such that $\Phi(g) = gH$ Its kernel is H therefore intuitively, this implies the notion of cyclic groups

Comment: SImply take the non-cyclic group $\;V\;$ of order $\;4\;$ and $\;H=1\;$, and the quotient is $\;V\;$ itself and non-cyclic. In fact, **any** group can be seen as the quotient of another group.

Comment: @Joanpemo Maybe OP means the quotient of a cyclic group is always cyclic?

Comment: @awllower Thank you. Maybe, though from the question I can't say.